# How to set alternative text for asp.button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vbscript

Can alt property used for asp button, not image button?? 
The text shown in my button is '**+**'. But while using JAWS for reading the page content, I need this button to be read with some other text rather than reading it as 'plus button'. 
I have applied alt property that seems not working. 
Need a help as early as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Either set the Tooltip property:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="+" ToolTip="plus button" />
```

which will render as a title attribute:

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="+" id="Button1" title="plus button" />
```

Or set the alt attribute directly:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="+" alt="plus button" />
```

which will render as

```
<input type="submit" name="Button1" value="+" id="Button1" alt="plus button" />
```

Note that the alt attribute is used to specify alternative text that is to be rendered when the element to which it is applied cannot be rendered, so usually this is used for images, less so for buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I have tried both title as well as alt. But both are not working... Can u tell me if there is any other reason for not working of both these...

Comment: The code is:

<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnAddRecipients" runat="server" OnClientClick="btnAddRecipients_OnClick()" Height="30px" Width="30px" Text="+"                                     onclick="btnAddRecipients_Click" />
 &nbsp;
</td>

Comment: @BPS: I don't see the alt or title attributes being set anywhere...?

Comment: Oops...here is the code-

<asp:Button ID="btnAddRecipients" runat="server" OnClientClick="btnAddRecipients_OnClick()" Height="30px" Width="30px" Text="+"                                    onclick="btnAddRecipients_Click" alt="Add Recipient" />

Comment: @BPS: This should work just fine. So the alt attribute is completely missing from the rendered HTML? Have you tried setting the attribute in code behind? (btnAddRecipients.Attributes.Add("alt", "xyz"))

Comment: I have tried through javascript and vbscript in the client side but not through code behind..let me try dat too....anyway thanx for your valuable help @matk